# Using DynamicObject when multi-targeting in NetStandard

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-core, .net-standard

I have the following implementation of `DynamicObject`:

```
public sealed class DynamicDictionary : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string tmpResult;
        if (!_dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out tmpResult))
        {
            result = null;
            return true;
        }

        result = tmpResult;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        _dictionary[binder.Name] = value.ToString();
        return true;
    }
}
```

When this is built in a project targeting the full framework e.g. `net451` or in a `netstandard1.6` project, the following code runs with no problem:

```
dynamic dic = new DynamicDictionary();
dic.Foo = "bar";    
string bar = dic.Foo;
```

However when I try to build this in a multi-target `netstandard` project (supporting both `Net451` and `netstandard1.6`) using the following `project.json`:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {      
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",        
        "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "4.3.0",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.3.0"
      },
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "NET_STANDARD" ]
      }
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "warningsAsErrors": true
  }
}
```

The project compiles with no error or warning and produces two dlls, one for each framework (`net451` and `netstandard1.6`).

Referencing the `netstandard1.6` version in a *Console* app running on `netcoreapp1.1` executes the sample code above with no problems however when I reference the `net451` dll on a *Console* app built against `net451` executing the sample code throws: 
`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll`

As far as I am aware this exception is only thrown when either of `TryGetMember()` or `TrySetMember()` methods in the `DynamicDictionary` class return `false` indicating the value could not be retrieved or set on the underlying dictionary.

Putting a break point on either of these methods revealed that they are never invoked even though I can see the value of "bar" in the underlying dictionary.

I suspect some dll have not been referenced correctly when building the multi-target project against `net451`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the debugger attached with first-chance exception catching on? (i.e. break on thrown) From what I have read, this exception does happen and is part of how dynamic works, however if this is bubbling up the stack to your code then that's a problem.

Comment: `project.json` is obsolete, so you are using the wrong tool and must change that first.